# Bootstrap 4 carousel controls don't appear

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with the Bootstrap 4 carousel. It's actually working the way it should, except that the previous/next icons will not show. I've looked up/tried the following:

-glyphicons are no longer supported

-tried putting controls inside div "carousel-inner"

-tried applying z-index to controls

-tried changing image sizes and icon colors in CSS

My code looks just like the Bootstrap docs and all the examples I've looked up. Please help! Thanks in advance.

page as it currently appears (obviously not even close to done) https://cdn.rawgit.com/Cookrp924/My-Portfolio/9c48827b/Job%20Portfolio.html

the code in question:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>About Me</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <h5>I am currently living in Raleigh, NC right next to the Research Triangle Park area. Through several friends and colleagues, I developed an interest in learning how to code and have been expanding my knowledge ever since. My resources include Free Code Camp, Colt Steele's "Web Developer Bootcamp", Codecademy, Stack Overflow and of course Google.</h5>
            <h5>I am currently open to new opportunities. Please contact me at: emailhere.com</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <img src="https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/19990238_1802039519806266_6452049826481461127_n.jpg?oh=5192b5fe6276a7df8be03aa31254cae6&oe=5B367A91" id="aboutmePic">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <h1>Skills</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3>My skillset currently includes JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. I also utilize frameworks and libraries such as Bootstrap and jQuery. I always strive to create projects that are not only functional but also work reliably and have simple, easy to navigate user interfaces.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <i class="devicon-javascript-plain colored"></i>
            <i class="devicon-html5-plain-wordmark colored"></i>
            <i class="devicon-css3-plain-wordmark colored"></i>
            <i class="devicon-bootstrap-plain-wordmark colored"></i>
            <i class="devicon-jquery-plain-wordmark colored"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <div class="carousel slide" id="projectCarousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#projectCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#projectCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#projectCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#projectCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#projectCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <a href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Cookrp924/Quote-Generator/cff1b444/QuoteGenerator.html"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34467782/41815477-17a21464-773a-11e8-8bf7-c2748cd13075.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <a href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Cookrp924/Wikipedia-Viewer/cd5e1683/Wiki.html"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34467782/41825874-c749c87c-77f2-11e8-9de6-58b48b1ca5fb.jpeg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <a href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Cookrp924/Local-Weather-App/37555f33/LocalWeather.html"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34467782/41827757-449b5a28-77ff-11e8-9e44-e37f8b6cd093.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <a href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Cookrp924/Tic-Tac-Toe/99e0b7f2/Tic-Tac-Toe.html"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34467782/41844177-647fe7d0-783d-11e8-88d7-4251b81a591d.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <a href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Cookrp924/Simon/4a4c0ea8/Simon.html"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34467782/41844777-43195570-783f-11e8-88ed-8bf0c40c7419.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#projectCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#projectCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually hiding your `prev` and `next` icons. Update your code like below.

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#projectCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#projectCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
</a>
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/54322/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried that, but the arrows still don't show up. This is my code at the moment. If someone can please come back to me quickly, that would be very much appreciated.

```
<head>

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Deganis on Wheels</title>

    <style>
        .carousel img{
            max-height: 450px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">

        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="C:\Users\ohdeg\Documents\Family website.html">Home</a>

        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="C:\Users\ohdeg\Documents\Family\Family Website Map Page.html">Map</a>

        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="C:\Users\ohdeg\Documents\Family\Family website Facts.html">Facts</a>

        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="C:\Users\ohdeg\Documents\Family\Family website Journal.html">Journal</a>

        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="C:\Users\ohdeg\Documents\Family\Family Website Videos.html">Videos</a>

    </nav>

    <center>
        <h1 class="mt-3">
            Deganis on Wheels
        </h1>

    <div id="carouselExampleControl" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://scontent.fdub3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/69250540_10157516532942838_2757624069254807552_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&_nc_oc=AQkuXrUeviY6CXoQkPxGem-bnVVa0UbQZOX5ErsQLekyjvWsaQFUE2MPwQJCDY0tsEw&_nc_ht=scontent.fdub3-1.fna&oh=cfed540908f484393112c64a69edbbed&oe=5E0FD771" class = "" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://scontent.fdub3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/68547946_10157516532207838_5519242750152671232_n.jpg?_nc_cat=109&_nc_oc=AQmqaeIU-05SDz6t8-ls6w90x1WTn5RX6CLIa1hJQ_A77XYJKjM68cTQyoHoxyC0z9Y&_nc_ht=scontent.fdub3-1.fna&oh=13afc36f27fe9bbcfb0d6deb0be08dea&oe=5E10D6A5" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="" alt="">

            </div>

        </div>

        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControl" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon">Previous</span>
        </a>

        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControl" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon">Next</span>
        </a>

    </div>

    </center>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<a class="carousel-control left carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="prev">
          </a>
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i><i class="fa fa-angle-left">
          </i>
          <div align="right" style="float:right">
            <a class="carousel-control right carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="next" style="align-text:right">
            </a>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
          </div>
```